# Etiqueta video no se ve en chromiun

Tags: html

tengo el siguiente código:

```
       <video class="img-inicio" src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="100%" height="auto"  
         muted preload="auto" loop autoplay></video>
```

El video se ve perfecto en Chrome pero en Chromium no se ve el video, alguna idea de las causas del problema?, cualquier ayuda que pudieran brindarme es bienvenida, saludos

Comment: Sale algo en la consola del navegador?

Comment: no sale nada pero en la parte en donde se debe ver el vídeo queda en blanco